# Error en busqueda de archivo con define

Tags: php

Obtengo este error

> ```
> !/usr/bin/php Failed to open ../gestionweb/includes/afip/certificado.crt
> ```

Pero el archivo si existe, con los otros archivos no ocurre nada:

Esta es la instruccion:

```
define ("CERT", "../gestionweb/includes/afip/certificado.crt");
```

Es decir con otros define no ocurre, pero no se que significa ese error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes definida una ruta relativa. Incluir el mismo archivo en una carpeta diferente te traera problemas. Puedes solucionarlo normalizando la ruta del archivo de forma **absoluta**:

```
define("CERT", dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/afip/certificado.crt");
```

Comment: hola obtengo esto: #!/usr/bin/php Failed to open C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionweb\includes\gestionweb\includes\afip\certificado.crt  Tengo que poner la barra invertida y quitar gestionweb/includes

Comment: @Caruso, fíjate que esta parte se repite dos veces en la ruta: `/gestionweb/includes`. Puedes hacer esto: **`define("CERT", dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/afip/certificado.crt");`**

Comment: solo reemplaza la ruta correcta relativa al archivo donde tienes el define

Comment: lo hice y se resolvio..muchas gracias